# Process.Start(someUri) fails when called from installer with InstallAllUsers == true

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, custom-action, process.start

When I create a Windows Installer setup project that uses a custom installer class and put a `Process.Start(someUri);` anywhere in that custom installer class, the call to Process.Start() fails if the setup project property `InstallAllUsers` is set to true. If I set InstallAllUsers to false, Process.Start() works as I'd expect. When Start() fails, no exceptions are thrown and any code following the call to Start() *is* still executed, but the uri I specify isn't opened.

I'm not having much luck finding an explanation for this. Can anyone shed some light on why this happens? Thanks!

**Edit:**
I'm growing suspicious this is a Chrome-specific anomaly. Process.Start() works as expected with IE. Since InstallAllUsers implies a machine level installation, I'm now wondering if the fact that Chrome is installed to a user-specific AppData directory is part (or all) of the problem.

Comment: Awww.... my VERY FIRST tumbleweed badge! That's going in the diary tonight.... ;)

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(SYSTEM.DIAGNOSTICS.PROCESS);k(PROCESS);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true

Found the issue. The Example for Process class in help has the following comment:

```
// url's are not considered documents. They can only be opened

// by passing them as arguments.
```

This means trying to use the "default browser" causes the problem. The application (IExplorer.exe) needs to be specified for Urls

Comment: Not sure that explains why the problem only exists in installer classes with the InstallAllUsers property set to true...? During normal operation of the program (e.g. not installing/uninstalling) Process.Start("url") works as expected.

Comment: It sort of works as expected... if you check the return value of Process.Start(), it will be false for a web page. So if the calling code is checking the return value and not checking what is being executed, it could branch incorrectly.

Comment: Actually, it returns null, not false.